# Why don't i see my android app's icon in fabric?

Tags: google-fabric

I have a question in Fabric home. When I added an iOS app in Fabric app's icon is showing. When I added a android app, it's icon isn't showing.

Can anyone help me?

[image: related image here]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Fabric doc:

> We will automatically upload your app’s icon when the app is first
>   added to Fabric. However, app icons can change! To update your app’s
>   icon, log into your account, head to your app’s [settings](https://fabric.io/settings/apps) and click on
>   the current icon. Select the new icon and upload it.

Possibly at the time of integration of your app to fabric, you've default app icon so you're getting default icon at fabric home.

No problem you can now change your icon with your original icon at fabric.

Comment: Possibly at the time of integration of your app to fabric, you've default app icon so you're getting default icon at fabric home.

I think that's the my problem.
Thank you.